# Obtain row means for columns in same group using metadata file

Tags: r, metadata

I have been trying to figure out a more efficient way to summarize rowMeans for various samples belonging to the same group. I couldn't find a good post to what I would think would be a common problem.

I'd like to have something more automated using a metadata file but can't figure it out. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

`file` looks like this:

| Target_Name | Target_position | Sample_1 | Sample_2 | Sample_3 | Sample_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Target-1 | 1 | 100 | 105 | 54 | 55 |
| Target-1 | 2 | 120 | 125 | 57 | 58 |

`metadata` looks like this:

| group | sample |
| --- | --- |
| Control | Sample_1 |
| Control | Sample_2 |
| Test | Sample_3 |
| Test | Sample_4 |

My Expected output looks like this:

| Target_Name | Target_position | Sample_1 | Sample_2 | Sample_3 | Sample_4 | Control_Mean | Test_Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Target-1 | 1 | 100 | 105 | 54 | 55 | 102.5 | 54.5 |
| Target-1 | 2 | 120 | 125 | 57 | 58 | 122.5 | 57.5 |

I am able to generate the expected output using

```
file$Control_Mean <- rowMeans(file[ , c(3,4)], na.rm=FALSE)
file$Test_Mean <- rowMeans(file[ , c(5,6)], na.rm=FALSE)
```

But I was wondering if there is a more automated approach, as the group names in my metadata file will be different all of the time and not just called Control or Test. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

**Packaged**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

**Input Data**

```r
# Data
file <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Target_Name, ~Target_position, ~Sample_1, ~Sample_2, ~Sample_3, ~Sample_4,
    "Target-1",               1L,      100L,      105L,       54L,       55L,
    "Target-1",               2L,      120L,      125L,       57L,       58L
  )


metadata <- tibble::tribble(
     ~group,    ~sample,
  "Control", "Sample_1",
  "Control", "Sample_2",
     "Test", "Sample_3",
     "Test", "Sample_4"
  )
```

**Solution**

```r
file %>% 
  pivot_longer(Sample_1:Sample_4, names_to = "sample", values_to = "value") %>% 
  left_join(metadata) %>% 
  group_by(Target_position, group) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Target_position, names_from = "group", values_from = "mean",
              names_prefix = "Mean_") %>% 
  left_join(file) %>% 
  select(Target_Name, Target_position, Sample_1:Sample_4, starts_with("Mean"))
```

**Output**

```r
## A tibble: 2 × 8
#  Target_Name Target_position Sample_1 Sample_2 Sample_3 Sample_4 Mean_Control Mean_Test
#  <chr>                 <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>        <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 Target-1                  1      100      105       54       55         102.5     54.5
#
#2 Target-1                  2      120      125       57       58         122.5     57.5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Will be very useful moving forward!

Answer (score 1):

Using RuamPimentel's very handy data,

```r
file %>%
  mutate(purrr::map_dfc(split(metadata$sample, metadata$group),
                        function(z) rowMeans(cur_data()[z])))
# # A tibble: 2 x 8
#   Target_Name Target_position Sample_1 Sample_2 Sample_3 Sample_4 Control  Test
#   <chr>                 <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Target-1                  1      100      105       54       55    102.  54.5
# 2 Target-1                  2      120      125       57       58    122.  57.5
```

Comment: I'm a fan of the premise of *"“programming, in essence, must become the act of reducing complexity to simplicity"* and *"Improve Code by Removing It"*. Not sure we can do much to reduce this code any further :-)